# Animate background image to another - CSS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My HEADER element has a background image and I need to swap it to another image after a 3 second delay, I have looked all over the internet and I cannot find a solution! I have tried CSS3 and Jquery and I just cant get it to work.

Because of the way the website is built, it has to be the background image of the element that changes and not a nested Div within the HEADER element.

---

### --- SOLVED / SOLUTION ---

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("header").delay(5000).queue(function() {
          $(this).css({
              "background-image": "url(<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/header-boy-hover.jpg)"
          });
      });
  });
```

CSS

```
header {
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in;
    transition:all 1s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: post your code using fiddle.

Comment: How do you want to animate it? Cross-fading? Sliding?

Comment: This will help you to post future questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added the best solution so far, but it needs tweeking.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked before - This should give you an answer

[Change CSS background-image with different intervals via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378360/change-css-background-image-with-different-intervals-via-jquery)

Comment: This solution works perfectly but it doesn't fade between images.

Comment: To fade image background colour use the following CSS on the element - Change the .2 to the duration of the fade: `-o-transition:background .2s ease-out, background .2s ease-in; -ms-transition:background .2s ease-out, background .2s ease-in; -moz-transition:background .2s ease-out, background .2s ease-in; -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background .2s ease-in; transition:background .2s ease-out, background .2s ease-in;`